# Delete all type: "deviceStopped" in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have setState that can delete if exactly knew the id is.

```
bloc.deleteNotifications(id: "162");
```

work ok for delete which id are 162.

```
bloc.getNotifications();
```

can display json of all.

```
[{"id":192,"attributes":{},"calendarId":0,"always":true,"type":"deviceStopped","notificators":"web,firebase"},{"id":193,"attributes":{},"calendarId":0,"always":true,"type":"deviceMoving","notificators":"web,firebase"},{"id":194,"attributes":{},"calendarId":0,"always":true,"type":"deviceOverspeed","notificators":"web,firebase"},{"id":195,"attributes":{},"calendarId":0,"always":true,"type":"deviceFuelDrop","notificators":"web,firebase"},{"id":196,"attributes":{},"calendarId":0,"always":true,"type":"ignitionOff","notificators":"web,firebase"},{"id":197,"attributes":{},"calendarId":0,"always":true,"type":"deviceStopped","notificators":"web,firebase"}]
```

My question is how to delete all id that contain "type": "deviceStopped"?

```
bloc.deleteNotifications(id: "162");
```

can only delete by id.

i was confuse about `.removeWhere()` and `.forEach()`. don't know both are suitable for using in this situation or not.

i have try with

```
bloc.deleteNotifications(id: 
           bloc.getNotifications().removeAt((type)=> type == "deviceStopped") //should fix this line //.removeWhere
         ).forEach("id");
```

did not work. also still trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find out which items have `"type": "deviceStopped"`:

```dart
final notificationsWithDeviceStopped = await bloc.getNotifications()
      .where((notification) => notification["type"] == "deviceStopped");
```

Then, map `notificationsWithDeviceStopped` to expose only their IDs:

```dart
final notificationIds = notificationsWithDeviceStopped
      .map((notification) => notification["id"]);
```

Finally, iterate over your IDs to delete each notification.

```dart
for (final id in notificationIds) {
  bloc.deleteNotifications(id: id); 
}
```

If you feel confident enough, you can chain those operations and end up with this:

```dart
await bloc.getNotifications()
      .where((notification) => notification["type"] == "deviceStopped")
      .map((notification) => notification["id"])
      .forEach((id) => bloc.deleteNotifications(id: id));
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, i got ════ Exception caught by gesture ═════
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'where'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: where(Closure: (dynamic) => bool)

Comment: You must await `getNotifications()`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: You should also declare the types you are working with, so `getNotifications()` would return `Future<Iterable<Notification>>`. It's impossible to efficiently code with `dynamic` everywhere.